# How to make "if" condition change automatically depending on Command Line Argument in Java?

Tags: java, if-statement, command-line-arguments

In my code, if condition should change depending on command line argument.
For example in the code below:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
{
  if (a == 2)
     if ((i % 25 == 0) || ((i+1) % 25 == 0)
       // do something
  else if (a == 3)
    if ((i % 25 == 0) || ((i+1) % 25 == 0) || ((i + 2) % 25 == 0))
       // do something
  //...
}
```

If command line argument increases, the number of conditions inside "if" should increase as well. So "if" condition depends on Command line argument which can be between 1 and 50. I need some optimal way to avoid writing "if" condition 50 times.

Comment: you're adding another ((i+1) % 25 == 0) along with incrementing the number '1' depending on the a ?

Comment: You'll need to encapsulate the pattern into a function. `i` seems to be the only part that actually changes, so that should be a fairly easy pattern to represent. In a functional language, I'd fold `||` over a list from 0 to `a`. In an imperative lanuage, the same could be achieved using a for loop that uses an index from 0 to `a`, and an accumator that keeps track of whether or not the condition was met at least once.

Comment: @Carcigenicate Check out my answer. The latter is exactly what I did.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes Ya, I saw. I thought that was funny. I was on the train, so it took me like 5 minutes to type that comment.

Comment: @Kamil For the record, `//` is typically used to indicate comments in Java. `--` is the decrement operator, and will throw an error because a) `do` is a reserved keyword and `something` is an unexpected token.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind using boolean flags, you can do something like this:

```
boolean matched;
for (int iter = 0; iter < a; iter++) {
    if ((i + iter) % 25 == 0) {
        matched = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (matched) {
    //...
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work. What it does is loop through and, for every number `iter` between 0 and a-1, inclusive, check if i+iter mod 25 is zero. If it is, it sets the flag to `true`, regardless if it was already. This emulates the action of `||`, where it goes through each and, if any are true, stop comparing and return `true`. If you wanted to `&&`, you would set `matched` to be `true` by default, then `false` if it fails and break.

You could also wrap this in a method if you'd like:

```
boolean functionNameHere(int a, int i) {
    boolean matched;
    for (int iter = 0; iter < a; iter++) {
        if ((i + iter) % 25 == 0) {
            matched = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return matched;
}
```

Depending on how `i` and `a` are set up.

Comment: We both independently came to this solution, so this gets my vote.

Answer (score 0):

i think it should be like this

```
boolean ifArgument(int a) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a; j++){
        if ((i+j) % 25 == 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }return false;
}
```